# CRM 2011 cannot retrieve Encrypted strings in Custom Fields C#

Tags: c#, encryption, dynamics-crm-2011

I am facing a strange situation here:

I have a Custom Entity "My_Entity", and i have used CryptoJS on form save event Javascript to Encrypt two fields field1,field2. The fields are encrypted and then Saved in DB.

Now i want to retrive two fields back in Cutom Page C# to decrypt and display on Page:

I have a retrieve Multiple query:

```
       QueryExpression retrievquery = new QueryExpression("My_Entity");
       retrievquery.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(new string[]{"field1","field2"});
       EntityCollection AllRecords = Common.Common.RetrieveMultiple(retrievquery );
```

Now

```
Entity Legal= AllRecord.Entities[0];
```

Legal does not contain field1 and field2 but only GUID of the record. Is the any possible problem with the Encrypted text.

Answer (score 1):

You need to access to the `Entities` Collection of your `EntityCollection` object.

Try with

```
Entity Legal = AllRecords.Entities[0];
```

and it's better you check if you have at least one element before:

```
if (AllRecords.Entities.Count > 1) { ... }
```

Comment: Sorry that was a typo , but i found what was the real problem

Comment: if you fixed the problem and is not connected to the code you posted, please delete your question, in this way users looking for dynamics crm encryption will avoid it.

Comment: i have posted the answer, hope this help someone.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what's the problem,

But i checked in the Database and there were records with Required Fields as NULL.
I deleted all the junk records from DB by Using a delete query.

Then i retrieved and it worked fine. :)
So the real problem was the records having the required field NULL. The NULL was inserted into DB before the Field was Required. 
Hope this helps someone.

The Idea came to my mind because yesterday I was runing Custom Validation tool for Upgrade to CRM 2013 and it was not retrieving any CRM record. Then i google it and it said that there will be NULL WebResources.

Comment: i belive it will @AndriiButenko not good to vote down without any reason.